# export to excel file one specific row records

Tags: php, excel, export, laravel-5.1

in laravel 5.1 using maatweb / Excel package i need to export specific row records to excel file where the current page id is viewing

in my VlistController

```
public function export()
    {
        Excel::create('Company List', function($excel)
        {
            $excel->sheet('companies', function($sheet)
            {
                $data = Vlist::all();
                $data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
                $companies = [];
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $company['vname']= $value['vname'];
                    $company['vaddress']= $value['vaddress'];

                    $companies[] = $company;
                }
                $sheet->fromArray($companies);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

in my routes file

```
Route::get('/vlist/{vlist}/export' , 'VlistController@export');
```

in my show view

```
<li><a href="{{ action('VlistController@export', [$vlist->id])  }}"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Export Supplier : {!! $vlist->vname !!}</span></a></li>
```

the above controller code list all the records in excel sheet and i need only one specific record with the active id .

Comment: Not particularly familiar with Laravel, but you appear to pass the id as a parameter to the method, yet make no attempt in the method the retrieve it, or use it. presumably you would retrieve the id in the method then use it to limit the vlist results, something like `Vlist::where('id', '=', $id);`

Comment: Also, the the json encode/decode is pointless, just use object notation instead `$company['vname']= $value->vname;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you problem,you can try this code.You can query by your primary key to retrieve specific row.

```
public function export($id)
  {

    Excel::create('Company List', function($excel) use ($id)
    {
        $excel->sheet('companies', function($sheet) use ($id)
        {
            $data = Vlist::where('id', $id)->get();
            $data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
            $companies = [];
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $company['vname']= $value['vname'];
                $company['vaddress']= $value['vaddress'];

                $companies[] = $company;
            }
            $sheet->fromArray($companies);
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

and I don't think the following code is necessary.

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
$companies = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $company['vname']= $value['vname'];
        $company['vaddress']= $value['vaddress'];

         $companies[] = $company;
}
```

You can simply use the retrieve specific data

```
$data = Vlist::where('id', $id)->get(['vname', 'vaddress']);
```

and pass it to the method

```
$sheet->fromArray($data);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add how the OP sould retrieve the `$id` in the method - currently this will result in an undefined variable error, and the query will fail

Comment: adding this   $data = Vlist::where('id', '=', $id); gives undefined ($id)

Comment: Ok, i dont really use Laravel, as i mentioned in my comments, so i dont know if this is the correct way to pass the parameter, but looks about right to me

Comment: you should pass id through route and retrieve it a the method parameter.or if you know the $id you should use it.

Comment: public function export($id)
    {

        Excel::create('Company List', function($excel) use ($id)
        {
            $excel->sheet('companies', function($sheet) use ($id)
            {
                $data = Vlist::where('id', $id)->get(['vname', 'vaddress']);

                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }

Comment: Route::get('/vlist/{vlist}/export' , 'VlistController@export');

Comment: " i need only one specific record with the active id"  Do have the active id?if so then remove $id from "public function export($id)" and set $id = $your_active_id.

Comment: Route::get('/vlist/{id}/export' , 'VlistController@export');

Comment: Route::get('/visit/export/{id}', 'VisitController@export');          
Then you can retrieve the $id as a parameter of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I am in not sure about your Question, in my point of view you want to put(show) record form a specified row then my solution will work.

```
   $projectArr[] = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"];

  Excel::create('project_directory_result_sheet', function($excel) use($projectArr)  {
     $excel->sheet('Project_Directory_Result', function($sheet) use( $projectArr ) {
        $sheet->fromArray($projectArr,null, 'A3'); 
  }
}
```

In my solution noticeable point is **`$sheet->fromArray($projectArr,null, 'A3');`**

here i am giving 3 parameter value  that are 
first:Project Value Array.
second: show header true or false
third: row number where you want to represent record.